# Search and return multiple wildcard values in a single column

Tags: sql, oracle, clob

All -

I'm looking at a large volume of sql query history data. Ultimately I need to create a distinct list of tables used by each from a list of their executed queries.  Let's say my simplified table for this example is:

```
create table zwork_example (
username varchar2(50),
sql_text clob);
```

```
insert into zwork_example (username, sql_text)
values ('user1', 'schema1.table1, schema1.table2, schema2.table1, schema1.table1');

insert into zwork_example (username, sql_text)
Values ('user2', 'schema1.table3, schema1.table2, schema2.table1, schema1.table6');
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can search for schema1* and return N number of table names that belong to schema1?  In this example I have a particular schema I'm interested in, so I can explicitly state that schema1 is the only schema I'm interested in returning the table names from.

The output I would look for given this example is:

```
User        Schema          Tables
--------    --------        --------
User1       schema1         table1, table2
User2       schema1         table3, table2, table6
```

Answer (score 0):

`CLOB`, large data set ... doesn't sound *promising*. Read: it'll probably take some time to get the result. For such a small data set, see if this helps.

```
SQL> with
  2  search_for (schema) as
  3    (select 'schema1' from dual),
  4  temp as
  5    (select distinct
  6       username,
  7       trim(regexp_substr(dbms_lob.substr(sql_text, 32767), '[^,]+', 1, column_value)) col
  8     from zwork_example cross join
  9       table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
 10                           connect by level <= regexp_count(sql_text, ',') + 1
 11                          ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 12    )
 13  select
 14    t.username,
 15    s.schema,
 16    listagg(trim(replace(t.col, s.schema ||'.', null)), ', ') within group (order by null) tables
 17  from temp t join search_for s on instr(t.col, s.schema) > 0
 18  group by t.username, s.schema;

USERNAME   SCHEMA  TABLES
---------- ------- --------------------------------------------------
user1      schema1 table1, table2
user2      schema1 table2, table3, table6

SQL>
```

What does it do?

- `search_for` CTE contains a schema you're searching for (`schema1`, right?)
- `temp` CTE splits the `sql_text` into rows

  - moreover, in order to get `distinct` list of tables, I applied `dbms_lob.substr` to the column, hoping that you don't actually have strings longer than that (32767, that is)
- final query just aggregates tables it found - rows where schemas match

Answer (score 0):

For a large dataset you can use:

```sql
WITH search_string ( schema_name ) AS (
  SELECT 'schema1' FROM DUAL
),
matches ( username, sql_text, schema_name, end_pos, matches ) AS (
  SELECT username, 
         sql_text,
         schema_name,
         CASE
         WHEN sql_text LIKE schema_name || '%'
         THEN INSTR( sql_text, ',' )
         WHEN sql_text NOT LIKE ', ' || schema_name || '.'
         THEN 0
         ELSE INSTR(
                sql_text,
                ', ' || schema_name || '.',
                INSTR( sql_text, ', ' || schema_name || '.' ) + 3
              )
         END,
         CASE
         WHEN sql_text LIKE schema_name || '%'
         THEN EMPTY_CLOB() || SUBSTR(
                sql_text,
                LENGTH(schema_name || '.') + 1,
                INSTR( sql_text, ',' ) - LENGTH(schema_name || '.') - 1
              )
         WHEN INSTR( sql_text, ', ' || schema_name || '.' ) = 0
         THEN NULL
         WHEN INSTR( sql_text, ',', INSTR( sql_text, ', ' || schema_name || '.' ) + 3 ) = 0
         THEN EMPTY_CLOB() || SUBSTR(
                sql_text,
                INSTR( sql_text, ', ' || schema_name || '.' )
                  + LENGTH(', ' || schema_name || '.')
              )
         ELSE EMPTY_CLOB() || SUBSTR(
                sql_text,
                INSTR( sql_text, ', ' || schema_name || '.' )
                  + LENGTH(', ' || schema_name || '.'),
                INSTR( sql_text, ',', INSTR( sql_text, ', ' || schema_name || '.' ) + 3 )
                  - INSTR( sql_text, ', ' || schema_name || '.' )
                  - LENGTH(', ' || schema_name || '.')
              )
         END
  FROM   zwork_example
         CROSS JOIN search_string
UNION ALL
  SELECT username,
         sql_text,
         schema_name,
         INSTR(
           sql_text,
           ', ' || schema_name || '.',
           end_pos + 3
         ),
         matches
         || ', '
         || CASE 
            WHEN INSTR( sql_text, ',', end_pos + 1 ) = 0
            THEN SUBSTR(
                   sql_text,
                   end_pos + LENGTH(', ' || schema_name || '.')
                 )
            ELSE SUBSTR(
                   sql_text,
                   end_pos + LENGTH(', ' || schema_name || '.'),
                   INSTR( sql_text, ',', end_pos + 1 )
                     - end_pos - LENGTH(', ' || schema_name || '.')
                 )
            END
  FROM   matches
  WHERE  end_pos > 0
  
)
SELECT username,
       matches
FROM   matches
WHERE  end_pos = 0;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
create table zwork_example (
  username varchar2(50),
  sql_text clob
);

DECLARE
  v_text CLOB;
BEGIN
  insert into zwork_example (username, sql_text)
  values ('user1', 'schema1.table1, schema1.table2, schema2.table1, schema1.table1');

  insert into zwork_example (username, sql_text)
  Values ('user2', 'schema1.table3, schema1.table2, schema2.table1, schema1.table6');

  insert into zwork_example (username, sql_text)
  Values ('user3', 'schema2.table3, schema3.table2, schema4.table1, schema2.table6');

  insert into zwork_example (username, sql_text)
  Values ('user4', 'schema2.table3, schema3.table2, schema4.table1, schema1.table6');

  v_text := 'schema1.table1';
  FOR i IN 2 .. 250 LOOP
    v_text := v_text || ', schema1.table' || i;
  END LOOP;
  insert into zwork_example (username, sql_text) values ( 'user5', v_text );
END;
/
```

Outputs:

> | USERNAME | MATCHES |
> | --- | --- |
> | user3 |  |
> | user4 | table6 |
> | user1 | table1, table2, table1 |
> | user2 | table3, table2, table6 |
> | user5 | table1, table2, table3, table4, table5, table6, table7, table8, table9, table10, table11, table12, table13, table14, table15, table16, table17, table18, table19, table20, table21, table22, table23, table24, table25, table26, table27, table28, table29, table30, table31, table32, table33, table34, table35, table36, table37, table38, table39, table40, table41, table42, table43, table44, table45, table46, table47, table48, table49, table50, table51, table52, table53, table54, table55, table56, table57, table58, table59, table60, table61, table62, table63, table64, table65, table66, table67, table68, table69, table70, table71, table72, table73, table74, table75, table76, table77, table78, table79, table80, table81, table82, table83, table84, table85, table86, table87, table88, table89, table90, table91, table92, table93, table94, table95, table96, table97, table98, table99, table100, table101, table102, table103, table104, table105, table106, table107, table108, table109, table110, table111, table112, table113, table114, table115, table116, table117, table118, table119, table120, table121, table122, table123, table124, table125, table126, table127, table128, table129, table130, table131, table132, table133, table134, table135, table136, table137, table138, table139, table140, table141, table142, table143, table144, table145, table146, table147, table148, table149, table150, table151, table152, table153, table154, table155, table156, table157, table158, table159, table160, table161, table162, table163, table164, table165, table166, table167, table168, table169, table170, table171, table172, table173, table174, table175, table176, table177, table178, table179, table180, table181, table182, table183, table184, table185, table186, table187, table188, table189, table190, table191, table192, table193, table194, table195, table196, table197, table198, table199, table200, table201, table202, table203, table204, table205, table206, table207, table208, table209, table210, table211, table212, table213, table214, table215, table216, table217, table218, table219, table220, table221, table222, table223, table224, table225, table226, table227, table228, table229, table230, table231, table232, table233, table234, table235, table236, table237, table238, table239, table240, table241, table242, table243, table244, table245, table246, table247, table248, table249, table250 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=bc0bdb4e1e9b4ac0d7c81b190d43315e)*

Comment: Thanks, lots to learn here. In your CLOB solution, could you help to modify that to account for a few inaccuracies in my original problem statement?  Ultimately, I need to use this to search some large sql statements stored in sql_text to pull out the table and schemas when they follow the format of [schema].[table].  I understand that using a period as an anchor and returning forward and backword words like '\w+\.+\w+' will pull in some bad data, aliases, etc but I think the results will be good enough and sql is generated by an etl tool so consistency is there.